# Entity Framework caching for identical actions by default

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I added EF file and didn't change any of the configuration.
Lets say I have the following code:

```
Container container = new Container();
var e1 = container.SomeEntity.First(x => x.Id == 1);
var e2 = container.SomeEntity.First(x => x.Id == 1);
```

Will it go to DB on the second identical call?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I used profiler. It goes to DB on each call.

Comment: EF does store it in the local cache.  You can see it at contain.SomeEntity.Local.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592872.aspx